# Code not Stepping into class methods iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, class

When i run through my code, i noticed that none of my methods step into class methods. e.g.

I have a class called:

Person.h

```
@interface Person : UIViewController

- (BOOL)personName:(NSString *)person;

@end
```

Person.m

```
@implementation Person

- (BOOL)personName:(NSString *)person;
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

---

Now here is my people.h class: From here i want to call a method from the person class.

```
@interface People : UIViewController

@property () Person *person;

@end
```

People.m

```
- (IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    BOOL personhasNameBOB = [person personName:@"Bob"];
}
```

However "[person personName:@"Bob"]; gets called - but never entered the method inside the Person Class. When adding a break point and stepping through, it simply navigates to people.h and highlights "@property () Person *person;" then moves back to 'people.m' and moves to the next line.

What possible reasons could there be for it not entering the class method?

Comment: Are you instantiating your "Person" object ? i.e. do you call *person = [[Person alloc] init];* ? Because if not, you would try to call an instance method on a non instantiated object, which would not work.

Comment: @rdurand: it would "work", just not do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create the object before assigning a property to an object. So a line like has to be present:

> Person *personhasNameBOB = [[Person alloc]init];

Comment: You mean *person = [[Person alloc] init];* Don't mess up the var names :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to create strong reference to Person class. Replace line:

`@property () Person *person`;

with

```
@property (strong) Person *person;
```

I assume that you allocate and initialise person object somewhere,for example in viewDidLoad.

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because that line actually contains two method calls - first `-[People person]` to get the person object, and then `-[Person personName:]`. Instead of the step over, do a step into, step out, and then step into again.